# How to deploy postgres_exporter on the Docker and connect to prometheus

Tags: postgresql, docker, prometheus

I have a server on Debian 8 where docker is installed. The approach is needed in containers. The container is installed postgres 9.6. I want to set up data collection of the pg_stat_statements table in prometheus via postgres_exporter from PostgreSQL, and then look at the graph via grafana. Deployment grafana and Prometheus did according to the instructions:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom
$ cd dockprom
$ docker-compose up -d
```

In prometheus.yml added:

```
- job_name: 'postgres-exporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9187']
```

But I have problem with postgres-exporter: 
[Prometheus targets status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNr2B.png)

Took this export statistics for PostgreSQL: [link](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter). I tried to deploy to docker with different ports, but Prometheus did not want to connect to him. Tell me, please, how properly install and deploy?

Comment: If you don't use `network_mode: host` in docker-compose.yml, your localhost inside container is different than localhost in your host. You can define your own docker network or declare `network_mode: host` in every docker-compose service to achive connection among them.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrape only postgresdb metrics ,you  can just use docker commands instead of docker-compose

```
sudo docker run --name postgres-exporter -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://<postgresdb_user_name>:<postgres_db_password>@<postgres_vm_ip>:<postgresdb_port>/?sslmode=disable" -p 9187:9187 wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
```

For me the full command I executed was

```
sudo docker run --name postgres-exporter -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://postgres:postgrespassword@10.0.0.31:5432/?sslmode=disable" -p 9187:9187 wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
```

Then added scraping point in prometheus.yml file

```
- job_name: postgres_100031
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['10.0.0.31:9187']
```

Restart Prometheus service